# BRISK and FREAK descriptors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-extraction, matlab-cvst, freak

I'm using MATLAB 2014a for extracting **BRISK** and **FREAK** descriptors. I couldn't find any option to reduce the bit string size to **128** or **256**, they both generated as **512** bits. I think **FREAK** does not allow this by algorithm but **BRISK** should allow. Does anyone know if I can reduce the dimension of BRISK descriptor? If yes how can I?

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://www.asl.ethz.ch/people/lestefan/personal/BRISK) is the official code. See if they have provided an option.

Comment: Official code for both BRISK and FREAK?

Comment: That is official code for BRISK. [This](http://lts2www.epfl.ch/software) is official code for FREAK.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the current MATLAB implementation only computes the 512 bit BRISK descriptor.